# After a plain text encryption the file size increases upto which percentage?

Tags: file, encryption, size

In RSA algorithm the plain text length is 6, encrypted text length is 128. how the file size increases after encryption? If you want more security then you got much bigger encrypted files sizes,comparatively than the original! is it true?. AES don't have that much changes on file size after encryption. What are all the other standards increases the file size after encryption? kindly help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RSA you have a modulus usually referred to as N.  The length of N is the key size of that RSA implementation.  Your encrypted output will typically be as many bits long as N is.  You can expect this for all asymmetric encryption.  In symmetric encryption with block ciphers, on the other hand, the cipher text will be the same length as the plain text rounded up to the nearest even block, or one full block longer with some padding schemes under some conditions.  And with stream ciphers, which are also symmetrical, your cipher text will usually be the same length as the plain text.  Bear in mind there is additional overhead with some modes, such as an unencrypted IV that must also be included with the cipher text so it can be properly decrypted.

Comment: Your elaborated answer helps me to get a clear idea about cryptography types. Security wise, which type of encryption(symmetric,asymmetric) is the best(don't bother about the computational time and surely increase in file size after encryption)?   @WDS

Comment: @M.G.Gouthamanaath "Best" is very much subject to requirements.  Asymmetric crypto is used in key exchanges and digital signatures where symmetric crypto cannot be used at all.  After all, the same key that would verify a signature in a symmetric scheme could also forge a new signature.  So as a general guide, you use asymmetrical for key exchange and digital signatures, symmetrical block ciphers for encrypted storage, and symmetrical stream ciphers for real-time communications.  But this is a simple summary; there are lots of subtleties to learn.

Comment: As for security, all can be made unbreakable within a feasible period of time by any publicly known means as long as you use a large enough key.  But "large" enough varies.  I think as a rough comparison, 256 AES is comparable to 512 bit elliptic curve or 2048 bit RSA.  All three are secure enough even for sensitive financial information right now.